# Php separar json ond campos são sem padrão

Tags: php

Estou tentando separar uma string json que retorna do banco mas sem sucesso ate o momento.O problema esta na tag questionario, onde o resultado é dinamico e sempre sera diferente. Preciso separar a pergunta do questionario e sua resposta conforme a pesquisa. Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

```
foreach ($dadosPS as $dados) {
       $array['nome_pesquisa'] = $dados['nome_pesquisa'];
       $array['questionario'] = $dados['questionario'];
      @$ret .= json_encode($array);
   }
  echo @$ret;




{"nome_pesquisa":"FORMA DE PAGAMENTO","questionario":"{"Bom dia/Boa tarde! Sou do setor de pesquisas , gostaria de falar com o responsável pela Razão Social XXXX ?":"Sim","Hoje o Sr(a) utiliza dinheiro como forma de pagamento de suas compras , caso disponibilizassemos o pagamento via cartão de débito, o Sr(a) gostaria ?":"Não","Também disponibilizamos o modo de pagamento via Boleto, você gostaria de optar por esta forma de pagamento ?":"Sim"}"},
{"nome_pesquisa":"nota fiscal parceria","questionario":"{"Nome":"teste","Você é responsu00e1vel pelo recebimento da entrega de parceria ?":"sim","Você recebeu a nota fiscal ?":"não","Porque não recebeu ?":"preço não acordado"}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já experimentou um `foreach` na *array* `$dados['questionario']`?

Aliás, seu *JSON* está errado:
`[...]nario":"{"Bom dia[...]` deveria ser `[...]nario":{"Bom dia[...]`.

Mas no caso de retornar mais de um objeto na pesquisa, seu JSON deveria ser assim:

```
{
    "pesquisa1": {
        "nome_pesquisa": "FORMA DE PAGAMENTO",
        "questionario": {
            "Bom dia/Boa tarde! Sou do setor de pesquisas , gostaria de falar com o responsável pela Razão Social XXXX ?": "Sim",
            "Hoje o Sr(a) utiliza dinheiro como forma de pagamento de suas compras , caso disponibilizassemos o pagamento via cartão de débito, o Sr(a) gostaria ?": "Não",
            "Também disponibilizamos o modo de pagamento via Boleto, você gostaria de optar por esta forma de pagamento ?": "Sim"
        }
    },
    "pesquisa2": {
        "nome_pesquisa": "nota fiscal parceria",
        "questionario": {
            "Nome": "teste",
            "Você é responsu00e1vel pelo recebimento da entrega de parceria ?": "sim",
            "Você recebeu a nota fiscal ?": "não",
            "Porque não recebeu ?": "preço não acordado"
        }
    }
}
```

Agora teremos os dados formatadinhos no PHP com um `json_decode`:

```
Array
(
    [pesquisa1] => Array
        (
            [nome_pesquisa] => FORMA DE PAGAMENTO
            [questionario] => Array
                (
                    [Bom dia/Boa tarde! Sou do setor de pesquisas , gostaria de falar com o responsável pela Razão Social XXXX ?] => Sim
                    [Hoje o Sr(a) utiliza dinheiro como forma de pagamento de suas compras , caso disponibilizassemos o pagamento via cartão de débito, o Sr(a) gostaria ?] => Não
                    [Também disponibilizamos o modo de pagamento via Boleto, você gostaria de optar por esta forma de pagamento ?] => Sim
                )

        )

    [pesquisa2] => Array
        (
            [nome_pesquisa] => nota fiscal parceria
            [questionario] => Array
                (
                    [Nome] => teste
                    [Você é responsu00e1vel pelo recebimento da entrega de parceria ?] => sim
                    [Você recebeu a nota fiscal ?] => não
                    [Porque não recebeu ?] => preço não acordado
                )

        )

)
```

Pra facilitar, eu criei um arquivo pros dados *JSON* e "puxei" o conteúdo no PHP, pra então decodificar. O resultado foi o seguinte:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("arquivo_json.json"), true);

foreach($json['pesquisa1']['questionario'] as $pergunta => $resposta){
    echo "Pergunta: " . $pergunta . " / Resposta: " . $resposta . "<br>";
}
```

Saída ficou assim:

```
//Pergunta: Bom dia/Boa tarde! Sou do setor de pesquisas , gostaria de falar com o responsável pela Razão Social XXXX ? / Resposta: Sim
//Pergunta: Hoje o Sr(a) utiliza dinheiro como forma de pagamento de suas compras , caso disponibilizassemos o pagamento via cartão de débito, o Sr(a) gostaria ? / Resposta: Não
//Pergunta: Também disponibilizamos o modo de pagamento via Boleto, você gostaria de optar por esta forma de pagamento ? / Resposta: Sim
```

> [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) é uma excelente ferramenta pra validar seu JSON.
>
> [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) decodifica uma string JSON.
>
> [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) lê todo o conteúdo de um arquivo para uma string.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: LipESprY, obrigado pelo retorno isso ja deu uma esclarecida onde estou errando, bom , funcionou perfeitamente , então neste caso vou precisar salvar para o banco na estrutura mas uma duvida, como cada pesquisa esta em um formulario diferente elas nao terão o nome de pesquisa1,pesquisa2, pesquisa3.... mas sim somente "pesquisa". com isso em mente consigo realizar o resultado delas colocando a saida de cada resultado, em linha conforme cada grupo de pesquisa?

Comment: Sim. Sem problemas. Só organizei dessa forma baseando no código que vc postou.